# sort() method using paginate() runs but does nothing

Tags: sorting, laravel, laravel-4

If I query my eloquent model using the get() fetch method I'm able to use the sort() to rearrange my collection. If I simply switch from get() to paginate(10) the sort stops working. Laravel indeed runs through my user defined function in both cases but doesn't apply the sort result in the paginate() case. If it runs the function why I do not get my results sorted?

Example:

```
$data = MyModel::with('other_model').get();
$data->sort(function($a, $b)
{
    if($a->other_model->field == $b->other_model->field) return 0;
    return $a->other_model->field > $b->other_model->field 1 : -1;
});
dd($data->toArray());
```

My $data collection is now sorted based on my function. Now if I simply change it from a get() to a paginate() no error occurs, the functions runs several times with the correct values and at the end the sorted values seem to be ignored. No errors!!

```
$data = MyModel::with('other_model').paginate(10); // <- HERE
$data->sort(function($a, $b)
{
    if($a->other_model->field == $b->other_model->field) return 0;
    return $a->other_model->field > $b->other_model->field 1 : -1;
});
dd($data->toArray());
```

I understand that in the second example I get a paginator model not a direct collection. But paginator contains a collections inside of it I think.

**I'm not looking for a workaround, I just want to now if I can or not sort data as result of a paginate() fetch method?**

Comment: Any code? Pretty difficult to help you out when we have nothing to go on.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `sort` on `Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator` object but You may use `take` and `offset` to get specific ammount of records from a specific offset, for example:

```
$myModels = MyModel::with('other_model')->take(10)->offset(5)->get();
```

This will select `10` records from the `6th` record, so, you may use `sort` on `$data` and then you may manually build the pagination links using something this:

```
$data = Paginator::make($myModels->toArray(), $post->count(), 5);
```

So, you may use something like this in your view:

```
$data->links();
```

Check the [Pagination](http://laravel.com/docs/pagination#usage) class (`Creating A Paginator Manually`).

Comment: This is indeed a good ideia. I pulled out the collection from the paginator via getCollection() and then used your second line of code to recreate the paginator. This looks messy to me... In my opinion we should be able to use collection methods directly in the paginator items.